# Close-Vote impossible due to "question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer"

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplicate target erroneously rejected although it has upvoted/accepted answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165921/duplicate-target-erroneously-rejected-although-it-has-upvoted-accepted-answers)

I'm getting this information since lately:

> This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer

when i try to close a duplicate question.

This is the original: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644054/making-checkbox-field-of-gridview-editable

This is what i've tried to close: [Changing the state of check box in grid view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644494/changing-the-state-of-check-box-in-grid-view)

So OP didn't know that he can edit his question instead of asking a new.

Why can't i vote-to-close the duplicate question anymore? What is best practice in this case?

Comment: The original question has been removed by the asker. Could this be the reason for the message?

Comment: No, it was deleted 2 hours ago, but the message came so long as the question i wanted to link as duplicate has no upvoted answers. But you're right, it was deleted from OP since his new question has an accepted answer now.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe: why  should this be closed as duplicate although it is  the oldest? Funny question considering this issue.

Comment: It’s actually duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165928/we-should-be-able-to-close-questions-as-duplicates-of-any-question