# Duplicate target erroneously rejected although it has upvoted/accepted answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, duplicate-questions

[This review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/1437238) is not possible to finish, because I get that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651731/is-there-possibility-to-invoke-other-methods-instructions-before-main-when-run) can not be closed as a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439871/can-you-print-anything-in-c-before-entering-into-the-main-function), because it has no accepted or upvoted answer (although it has two answers - each with 6 upvotes).

Comment: I have the same problem with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653574/hiding-specific-legend-items)

Comment: This same thing is happening for manual close votes on Arqade, too.

Comment: Funny - It will let you flag as duplicate to a question with No answers.

Comment: @mateo_salta interesting. sounds like somebody forgot a negation :)

Comment: [Bug also present on Ask Ubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/5967/88802).

Comment: Still happening on SO. I can't VTC [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657065/what-is-the-point-of-using-hash-bang-routing).

Comment: Just happened for me, so not status-completed.

Comment: And just happened to me as well (on http://stackoverflow.com/q/14657351/179910, in case a mod can bypass the checking, and take care of the dupe).

Answer (score 7):

Sorry about this - the test was inadvertently negated, so it *only* let you close questions as duplicates of questions with no answers.

PSA: don't write production code when you're sick. It might catch something from you!

Comment: Lol? No unit testing?! You guys just failed code review in my team! Wait, that's a point - no code review?!

Comment: I'm -1ing this because putting untested code into production is just... WTF.

Comment: The worst of it is, I *did* test it - but I didn't test it with a user who wasn't me.

Answer (score 6):

The bug still exists as of a few minutes ago. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/1435957:) what it looks like:
[image: Bug screenshot]

I accessed this one from the review queue.

The question is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14647153/how-do-you-install-pip-on-windows-7-64-bit, which is proposed as a duplicate of [How do I install pip on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows), which has 10 answers, with the accepted one with 175 upvotes.

Possibly related is that the answer is community wiki. But the other instances linked have the same issue but are not CW.

---

The same thing happens when you access the close dialog from the question itself (clicking on Close):
[image: From the question]

Mooing Duck gives another example:
[image: Broken]

Comment: [and here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LSKea.png)

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172798/how-to-draw-an-oval-in-html5-canvas) (+25, Top answer +48/accept) refuses to be a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657456/porting-delphi-canvas-ellipse-function-to-javascript-arc-function#14657456)

Comment: Another example: [How to remove white space just between brackets [] ?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63335) duplicate of [Replace text between brackets](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/52793) (which has a +2 accepted answer).

Answer (score 2):

Another example: I wanted to mark [scoped_ptr ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657449/smart-pointers-ownership) as a duplicate of [What is a smart pointer and when should I use one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one), which has 17 answers. The top answer has 239 score.