# Duplicate does not have upvoted answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I can't close [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19430618/error-unknown-punctuation-string-12) as duplicate [of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355751/mysql-unknown-punctuation-string-12-error).

[image: duplicate error]

It clearly is the same user that created another account and asked the same thing again. But now I can't vote as duplicate.

<sub>There is [a dup of this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165818/close-vote-impossible-due-to-question-does-not-have-an-upvoted-or-accepted-answ) but it seems to be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).</sub>

Comment: That is tricksy, as non fraudulant sock puppeting is allowed, and to-other-user duplicates can't be closed without good answers

Comment: Upvote the other answer, close as duplicate, unvote the other answer

Comment: @random That's kinda cruel.

Comment: I think this is just a ploy to get us to upvote your answer so the question can be closed as a dupe ;)

Comment: @Servy: You caught me :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flag it for mod attention.  They are able to close anything as a duplicate of anything, even if there are no upvoted answers, if indeed these are the same user.