# How to close duplicated questions ... when the "duplicate" doesn't have an answer?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192961/listview-requires-two-touches-touchscreen-where-the-mouse-uses-one-click) explicitly says:

> This question was asked a few years ago by @moggizx, here: some-existing-question
>
> I've been unable to find a similar question, or an answer for this so I thought I'd try asking it again

Natural thing; I went to "close as duplicated" - but that is not possible, because `some-existing-question` has no answers.

I saw [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165818/close-vote-impossible-due-to-question-does-not-have-an-upvoted-or-accepted-answ) on meta - but that leads to *Duplicate target erroneously rejected although it has upvoted/accepted answers*. Doesn't apply here.

And [how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) doesn't cover this scenario either, does it?

Comment: Direct answer: you can't close as duplicate of a question without answer on a non-meta site. So closing this as dupe of the original discussion of the feature where it was added.

Comment: now there are 3 _duplicate_ in the title

Comment: Is there a badge for that? If not,  why not? :-)

Comment: How to proceed in the Main site for such situations? In particular, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63978105/5675325).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Closing to an unanswered duplicate would not be conducive to adding to a Q & A  site's knowledge base.

I've downvoted and voted to close the question because it's a clear copy of another unanswered one. I believe this is the appropriate thing to do:

1. This course of action ought to dissuade folk from answering the newer question and instead inspire them to answer the older one.
2. It will also perhaps "bump" up interest in this particular topic. (My downvoting the question covers off this being recognised as an acceptable reason for re-asking).
3. Hopefully the newer question will eventually be closed off: it only requires 4 more votes.

Of course one potential course of action open to the OP (if they had sufficient reputation) would be to offer a bounty on the older question.